# move in to next tab panel using tabindex in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, tabindex

I have following bootstrap code snippet, after I click TabKey in TextBox (ID="txtMainCat") which is `TabIndex = 101` , I  want to open other tab which is `TabIndex = 102` , currently it doesn't ,

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" >
        <li tabindex="100" class="active"><a href="#BasicItemDetails" data-toggle="tab">Main Details</a></li>
        <li tabindex="102"><a href="#AssignItem" data-toggle="tab">Company Rules</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="BasicItemDetails">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMainCat" TabIndex="101">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="AssignItem">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMainCat2" TabIndex="103">
        </asp:TextBox>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

tired with following , seems like that one also not working

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});

// store the currently selected tab in the hash value
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
});

// on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
var hash = window.location.hash;
$('#myTab a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. In my case, I had a tab pane with two tabs in bootstrap and I wanted to be able to use the tab keys and shift + tab keys to change the focus of the input fields. This did not work with the bootrstap tab pane unfortunately, so therefore I made this code:

```
function initTabSwitches()
{
    $(".tabSwitchOnTab").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 9) { //tab
            if (!e.shiftKey) {
                if ($(this).attr("tabindex")) {
                    var newTabindex = parseInt($(this).attr("tabindex")) + 1;

                    focusOnInputInOtherTab(newTabindex, e);
                }
            }
            else //shift + tab
            {
                if ($(this).attr("tabindex")) {
                    var newTabindex = parseInt($(this).attr("tabindex")) - 1;

                    focusOnInputInOtherTab(newTabindex, e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function focusOnInputInOtherTab(tabindex, e) {
    var newInputToFocus = $("[tabindex=" + tabindex + "]");

    var parentTab = newInputToFocus.closest(".tab-pane");

    if (!parentTab.hasClass("active")) {
        $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
        $("[id^=Tab_]").parents().removeClass("active");

        parentTab.addClass("active").addClass("fade").addClass("in");
        $("#Tab_" + parentTab.attr("id")).parent().addClass("active");
        newInputToFocus.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Just add the class tabSwitchOnTab to the last input element of the first tab and the first element of the second tab. Make sure your tabindexes are correct.